# How can i write avro files into S3 in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to read streaming data from kafka topics and write into S3 in avro, or parquet, format. The datastream looks like json string but I am not able to convert and write into S3 in avro, or parquet, format.

I found some code snippets and tried

val sink = StreamingFileSink
      .forBulkFormat(new Path(outputS3Path), ParquetAvroWriters.forReflectRecord(classOf[myClass]))
      .build()

But I got "Type mismatch, expected SinkFunction[String], actual: StreamingFileSink[TextOut]" at the addSink

val stream = env
      .addSource(myConsumerSource)
      .addSink(sink)

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround solution you can use AWS Kinesis Firehose after your basic etl convert your SQL Query Flink table to String and write to Kinesis from AWS Console and then write to S3 as parquet.

https://github.com/kali786516/FlinkStreamAndSql/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/aws/examples/kinesis/producer/TransactionExample/TransactionProducer.scala

https://github.com/kali786516/FlinkStreamAndSql/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/aws/examples/kinesis/producer/TransactionExample/TransactionProducer.scala

Kafka Example:-
https://github.com/kali786516/FlinkStreamAndSql/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/aws/examples/kafka

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have that is working to store Parquet files into local system.

```scala
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.{Schema, SchemaBuilder}
import org.apache.flink.core.fs.Path
import org.apache.flink.formats.parquet.avro.ParquetAvroWriters
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStreamSource
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.filesystem.StreamingFileSink

val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment()
env.enableCheckpointing(100)
val schema = SchemaBuilder
    .record("record")
    .fields()
    .requiredString("message")
    .endRecord()

val stream: DataStreamSource[GenericRecord] = env.fromCollection(genericRecordList)
val path = new Path(s"/tmp/flink-parquet-${System.currentTimeMillis()}")
val sink: StreamingFileSink[GenericRecord] = StreamingFileSink
    .forBulkFormat(path, ParquetAvroWriters.forGenericRecord(schema))
    .build()

stream.addSink(sink)
env.execute()
```